# Update JTable in SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingworker

I have a `JTable` which populates data from DB. I want to refresh data in `JTable` every 10 minutes (for testing 10 sec is enough). I tried do it with a `Thread`, but I found that it is not good idea, and I need to use `SwingWorker`

```
public class Monitor extends JFrame{

    JTable jtable = null;
    JTabbedPane jtp = null;
    JPanel jp1 = null;
    JPanel jp2 = null;
    JLabel label1 = null;
    JLabel label2 = null;

    public void setJTable(Vector data, Vector columnNames) {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jtable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jtable);
        jp1.add(scrollPane);
    }

    public void updateJTable(Vector data, Vector columnNames) {
        jtable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    }

    public Monitor() {

        setTitle("Monitor System");

        //Panel with tabs for navigation
        jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        getContentPane().add(jtp);

        //tab1, info from dba_jobs
        jp1 = new JPanel();

        //tab2 info from QueueInfo
        jp2 = new JPanel();
        label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setText("tab1");

        label2 = new JLabel();
        label2.setText("tab2");

        jp1.add(label1);
        jp2.add(label2);

        jtp.add("Tab1", jp1);
        jtp.add("Tab2", jp2);
    }

}
```

And my `Demo` class:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException  {

        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        Vector<Vector> rowData = new Vector<Vector>();
        DBMonitor dbmonitor = new DBMonitor();
        Monitor monitor = new Monitor();

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        rowData = dbmonitor.getJobsData();
        columnNames = dbmonitor.getColumnNames();
        monitor.setJTable(rowData, columnNames);
        monitor.setSize((int) dim.getWidth(), (int) dim.getHeight());
        monitor.setVisible(true);

        boolean interrupt = true;

        while (interrupt) {
            try {

                rowData = dbmonitor.getJobsData();
                columnNames = dbmonitor.getColumnNames();
                monitor.updateJTable(rowData, columnNames);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    return;
                } 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SLEEP!");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

How I can do it with `SwingWorker`? I don't get a concept of that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `doInBackground()` method of the SwingWorker you have you while loop that:

1. retrieves the data from the database
2. creates your TableModel
3. use the `publish()` method of the SwingWorker to pass the TableModel to the 'process()` method of your SwingWorker
4. sleeps for 10 seconds

Then in the `process()` method of the SwingWorker you:

1. use the TableModel that was passed to the `process()` method to update your JTable.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) for more information and a working example or search the forum for more `SwingWorker` examples.

Comment: That was going to be by my "other" option, so +1 to you

Comment: `I have read the tutorial, but they drive me crazy, because none may put just simple example.` - it is simple and does almost exactly what I described. All you need to do is modify the example to create and publish your TableModel instead of the "FlipPair". Then you add a Thread.sleep() to the loop. In the process() method you then set the model to the table. I really don't know how it gets any easier than that. Of course you actually have to download and run the code first.

Comment: I got it after I downloaded and launched example. Thanks a lot and sorry for my lazy.

Comment: -1mio for 2. creates your TableModel, not this Object should be prepared as local variable, not created in Worker Thread

Answer (score 1):

First, I would start with a `Timer` of some sort, I'm going to use a Swing Timer as it easy, but you could use a `java.util.Timer` instead...

```
private Timer updateTimer;

//...

updateTimer = new Time(10000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionListener(ActionEvent e) {
    }
});
updateTimer.setRepeats(false);
updateTimer.start();
```

This allows you to be notified in about 10 seconds time...

Then you need a `SwingWorker` that can do the actual work...

```
public class UpdateWorker extends SwingWorker<TableModel, Void> {

    private Monitor monitor;
    private Timer updateTimer;

    public UpdateWorker(Monitor monitor, Timer updateTimer) {
        this.monitor = monitor;
        this.updateTimer = updateTimer;
    }

    @Override
    protected TableModel doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Vector<Vector> rowData = dbmonitor.getJobsData();
        Vector columnNames = dbmonitor.getColumnNames();

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
        return model;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            TableModel model = get();
            monitor.updateTable(model);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        updateTimer.restart();
    }
}
```

Now in the `actionPerformed` method of the `ActionListener` assigned to the timer, you would do something like..

```
public void actionListener(ActionEvent e) {
    UpdateWorker worker = new UpdateWorker(monitor, this);
    worker.execute();
}
```

To execute the worker.  The reason for having a non-repeating timer is to ensure that the next update is set for `n` seconds from when the update completes, so you don't get overlapping updates

Oh, and this will require to update your `Monitor` to accept a `TableModel` rather then the `Vector`s you are using to create one, it's just simpler that way...

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, and I become understand it. Could you say me, where to execute first and last part of your code? In class where I have `main()` method?

Comment: @Beezy, have you read the tutorial yet and played with the working example?

Comment: @Beezy That's up to you, you start the timer where it makes sense for you to do so

Comment: @camickr, I have read the tutorial, but they drive me crazy, because none may put just simple example.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, what do you mean `updateTimer = new UpdateTimer`? Because there are no `UpdateTimer` class. If I use `Timer` class instance of `UpdateTimer`, there is no `actionListener` method to `Override`. And where execute `actionListener` method from the last part code? Excuse me, if I ask simple and stupid questions.

Comment: @Beezy Sorry, my bad, it's suppose to be `Timer` :P

Comment: @Beezy The last `actionListener` section should replace the empty implementation where the timer is created, otherwise you would have been reading forward...

Comment: -1mio for creating a JComponent/its model inside Worker Thread, in doInBackground(), get(); is designated to returns an exception

Comment: @mKorbel Ahh, where?  It creates a new `TableModel` in `doInBackground`, returns and uses `get` to retrieve the value within the context of the EDT, there is no creation of any component done within `doInBackground` at all.  The model is then applied to the `JTable` from within the `done` method, within the EDT...

Comment: @MadProgrammer you can to get() whole ResultSet agree, but whats happends if exception became as last event, or in the middle, anywhere, then get() by default returns only this exception, doesnt care somehow about your TableModel, that I'm talking about, another and most important issue is to create a Swing Object in Workers Thread

Comment: @mKorbel Because I'm creating a new TableModel, it has no means by which it interact with the UI/EDT until its attached to a JTable, there's no chance that it could possibly try and access the UI. I agree with the exception from get, hence the try-catch block. It's up to the OP to decide how to handle that situation as I have no context